# No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /ios/Pods/Local Podspecs/package.podspec.json

Tags: ios, flutter, cross-platform, flutter-platform-channel

No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /ios/Pods/Local Podspecs/.podspec.json

Answer (score 0):

- Remove the complaining package from your `.yaml` file
- Save the changes in your `.yaml` file, run `flutter pub get`
- cd into `ios` directory run `pod install`
- Add the packge that was complaining back to your `.yaml` file
- run `flutter pub get`
- Finally cd into `ios` directory run `pod install`, now run `flutter run` command the app should work.
- check this out https://github.com/jpush/janalytics-flutter-plugin/issues/7